# Duvida adicionar mensagem de "opção invalida" na minha calculdora de média em python

Tags: python

Criei a minha primeira calculadora de média.

Adicionei a opção de dar um ponto extra ao aluno com os comandos de `if` e else caso ele responda `"S"` para a pergunta. Segue a linha do código:

```
pt = input('você realizou a atividade de 1pt? S/N')

if pt == 'S':
    pt = 1
elif pt == 'N':
    pt = 0
else:
    print('comando invalido, digite apenas S ou N')
```

O código funciona apenas se se não correr o `else`, pois preciso de um valor numérico para `pt` no cálculo da média, que consigo adquirir atribuindo valores a `S` e `N` como mostrei antes, essa é a formula da media `m=(n1+n2+float(pt))/2`

Nessa situação o que posso fazer para o código retornar ou encerrar na situação do `else`? e o como eu poderia refinar o meu código?

```
import math

n1 = float(input('Digite sua primeira nota:'))

n2 = float(input('digite a segunda nota'))

pt = input('você realizou a atividade de 1pt? S/N')

if pt == 'S':
    pt = 1
elif pt == 'N':
    pt = 0
else:
    print('comando invalido, digite apenas S ou N')
    
m = (n1+n2+float(pt))/2

print('a sua media final é {:.1f}' .format(m,math.ceil(m)))

if m>=7.0:
    print('você foi aprovado, parabens!')
elif m>=6.0:
    print('entre em contato com o professor para uma atividade de recuperação')
else: 
    print('você não foi aprovado, infelizmente')
```

Answer (score -3):

Para encerrar a execução do seu código caso seja inserido uma opção inválida você pode incluir o comando exit() no seu código, ele finaliza a execução do script

```py
import math
n1=float(input('Digite sua primeira nota:'))
n2=float(input('digite a segunda nota'))
pt=input('você realizou a atividade de 1pt? S/N')
if pt == 'S':
    pt = 1
elif pt == 'N':
    pt = 0
else:
    print('comando invalido, digite apenas S ou N')
    #encerrando execução
    exit()
m=(n1+n2+float(pt))/2
print('a sua media final é {:.1f}' .format(m,math.ceil(m)))
if m>=7.0:
    print('você foi aprovado, parabens!')
elif m>=6.0:
    print('entre em contato com o professor para uma atividade de recuperação')
else: 
    print('você não foi aprovado, infelizmente')
```

Existem outras opções para finalizar seu algoritmo.

1. quit()
2. sys.exit() - importar a biblioteca sys
3. Aplicar seu código à uma função e retornar 0

**Implementado como função**

```py
import math


def calculaMedia(n1,n2,pt):
    if pt == 'S':
        pt = 1
    elif pt == 'N':
        pt = 0
    else:
        print('comando invalido, digite apenas S ou N')
        #encerrando execução
        return 0
        
    m=(n1+n2+float(pt))/2
    print('a sua media final é {:.1f}' .format(m,math.ceil(m)))
    if m>=7.0:
        print('você foi aprovado, parabens!')
    elif m>=6.0:
        print('entre em contato com o professor para uma atividade de recuperação')
    else: 
        print('você não foi aprovado, infelizmente')
        
n1=float(input('Digite sua primeira nota:'))
n2=float(input('digite a segunda nota'))
pt=input('você realizou a atividade de 1pt? S/N')
calculaMedia(n1,n2,pt)
```

**Possíveis refinamentos**

- Verificar se as notas inseridas são válidas (não são números
  negativos ou maiores que 10)
- Adicionar mais informações sobre a média final, como por exemplo a
  situação do aluno (aprovado, recuperação, reprovado)
- Melhorar a definição dos nomes das variáveis, caracterizando elas
  conforme o tipo de dado e uso (ex: n1 = nota1)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta e sugestões de refinamento